# How to Automate SharePoint Record Updates

Tags: windows, powershell, sharepoint

So we have an inventory list with details about each item, mostly drop down menus and check boxes, some comments and descriptions. These records are in SharePoint. Sometimes we need to update multiple items in there in addition to a large number of other steps and I am trying to automate most of these steps including the updates to their SharePoint record. What is the best way to go about this in PowerShell from any remote computer?

Would I connect to the database, find the record and and update the record there? Is there an easier way? I tried finding PowerShell CLI tools for SharePoint but I don't see them available anywhere.

For example, I might want to update this field here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the the best Automate update list item in SharePoint remotely is using CSOM(C# code) API.

Here is a demo about update list item for your reference:

```
// Starting with ClientContext, the constructor requires a URL to the 
// server running SharePoint. 
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://SiteUrl"); 

// Assume that the web has a list named "Announcements". 
List announcementsList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements"); 

// Assume there is a list item with ID=1. 
ListItem listItem = announcementsList.GetItemById(1); 

// Write a new value to the Body field of the Announcement item.
listItem["Body"] = "This is my new value!!"; 
listItem.Update(); 

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

For do authentication to access SharePoint, we can do as below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// set authentication of SharePoint online
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clientContext"></param>
    /// <param name="userName"></param>
    /// <param name="password"></param>
    public static void setOnlineCredential(ClientContext clientContext,string userName,string password)
    {
        //set the user name and password
        SecureString secureString = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
        {
            secureString.AppendChar(c);
        }
        clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, secureString);           
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// set authentication of SharePoint on-premise
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clientContext"></param>
    /// <param name="userName"></param>
    /// <param name="password"></param>
    /// <param name="domain"></param>
    public static void setClientCredential(ClientContext clientContext, string userName, string password, string domain)
    {
        clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
    }
```

If you want to use PowerShell, We can use PowerShell to use CSOM as this article talked: [CSOM SharePoint PowerShell Reference and Example Codes](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29518.csom-sharepoint-powershell-reference-and-example-codes.aspx) and we just need to modify the code above to be PowerShell code

Comment: Thanks, the problem here though is that you don't know the ID of the record you want to update. Nobody knows that, especially a long list of them. We only know the name of it, or rather one of the fields which is "HostName".